Is it possible to write bash completion function when arguments are in the form --arg=argval
How to write bash completion when the arguments have no spaces but =
For example myapp can take either --arg=argVal1 or --arg=argVal2
_myapp_completion() {
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts="--arg1 --arg2 --arg3" # List of valid options for your application

    case "${prev}" in
        --arg1)
            # If previous word is --arg1, complete the values
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "value1 value2 value3" -- "${cur}"))
            if [[ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
                # If only one completion option, remove space after --arg1=
                COMPREPLY=(${COMPREPLY[@]/#/${prev}=})
            fi
            return 0
            ;;
        *)
            # Default completion logic for other arguments
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "${opts}" -- "${cur}"))
            return 0
            ;;
    esac
}

complete -F _myapp_completion ./myapp

Above example myapp would take one of value1 value2 value3 after --arg1= without space.

Please [edit] your question and give us more detail. Ideally, explain how your script parses its options since what you describe is non-standard so presumably you have written your own parser and aren't using getopt or getopts.

That is not really relevant to the question, application is using google benchmark framework. Will update question with example bash completion script which doesn't work as required.
